# Let G be a group (not necessarily an Abelian group) of order 425. Prove that G must have an element of order 5.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-writing

This is what I have so far.  Mostly stuck a little on the $|G| = 16k + 1$ part so wanted a second opinion.

-Let $|G| = 425$

-Let $g$ be any non-identity element of $G$

-Using Lagrange’s Theorem $g$ has order $5, 17, 25, 85$ or $425\newcommand{ord}{\operatorname{ord}}$

-If $\ord(g)=5$ then we are done

-If $\ord(g)=25$ then $\ord(g^5)=5$ and we are done

-If $\ord(g)=85$ then $\ord(g^{17})=5$ and we are done

-If $\ord(g)=425$ then $\ord(g^{85})=5$ And we are done

-If none of these are true this suggests that all $424$ nonidentity elements have order $17$

-Hence $|G| = 16k + 1$ where $k$ is an integer.  Since there is no answer for $k$ then $G$ must have an element of order $5$.

Comment: This proof looks essentially complete but you should justify $|G|=16k+1$, which follows from partitioning all the non-identity elements into those which are in the same subgroup; since $\mathbb Z/17\mathbb Z$ is cyclic this can be done and puts them in groups of 16.

Comment: A more natural solution probably is to use Cauchy's theorem.

Answer (score 2):

To complete your proof, note that all non-identity elements of $G$ having order $17$ implies $G$ is a $p$-group with $p=17$, and hence $|G|=17^k$ for some positive $k$. But $425$ is not a power of $17$ and we are done.

Alternatively, the result immediately follows from Cauchy's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

If all non-identity elements of $G$ have order $17$, then the subgroups generated by two non-identity elements are either equal or intersect at the identity. Thus, if $G$ has $k$ subgroups of order $17$, then $G$ has order $16k+1$.